# Is every function from $\{1/n : n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{0\}$ to $\Bbb R$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

> **Q-** Consider $J=\{1/n : n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{0\}$. Let $f:J\to\Bbb R$ be any function. Show that $f$ is continuous in $J$.

**My attempt:**

I have proven $\forall a\in J$ such that $a=1/k$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$.

Let $a=\frac1k\in J$ be fixed
Case:1 
Consider the interval $J_k=\left(\frac1{k+1},\frac1{k-1}\right),$ if $ k>1$ then the only element of $J$ in $J_k$ is $\frac1k.$ Choose $\delta=\min\left\{\frac1k-\frac1{k+1},\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k\right\}$ if $k>1$ then we can conclude that if $x \in(a-\delta, a+\delta)$ then
$x=a .$ If $\varepsilon>0$ is given this $\delta$ will work.
Case: 2 If $k=1$ consider the interval $\left(\frac12, \frac32\right)$ then only element of $J$ in this interval is $1 .$ So for every $\varepsilon>0, \delta=\frac12$ will work.

Can we give any contidion to $f$ which assures continuity at $0$?

Comment: Consider using MathJax to format your posts, it goes a long way in helping us help you :)

Comment: Ok I'll take care of it next time..

Comment: Shall I edit this question also?

Comment: Yes please, especially because of terms like 1/k-1, that will cause confuston

Comment: What topology are you using on $J$? If it's the subspace topology inherited from $\Bbb R$, then I don't think the statement is true. What about the function $f\colon J\to\Bbb R$ defined by $f(0)=0$ and $f(1/n)=1$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Actually i'm learning how to use mathjax,maybe from next time i'll use that.but for now i just attached a clear image of my attempt.I think it will be alright.

Comment: **@Greg**  Yaa...I also think it may not be true ,but in the question we are supposed to prove this.

Comment: Actually, it’s expected that you use it every time. Here is the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr). To motivate you to make the appropriate edits, I’m downvoting and voting to close. You can @ me when you’re done and I’ll retract my votes.

Comment: As @GregMartin has said, the question is incorrect as stated. There are infinitely many counterexamples.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow if i restrict my domain to J={ 1/n: n∈N} .Then can i say every function is continuous? Then the argument i gave,will it work?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(1/n)=1$ for $n\in \Bbb N$ and let $f(0)=0.$ Then $f$ is not continuous because the sequence $(1/n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ converges to $0$   and $0$ belongs to $J,$ but the sequence $(f(1/n))_{n\in \Bbb N}$ does not converge to $f(0).$

A function $f:A\to B$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}C=^{def} \{x\in A: f(x)\in C\}$ is an open set in $A$ whenever $C$ is an open set in $B.$

If $A=\{1/n:N\in \Bbb N\}$ then $\{x\}$ is open in $A$ whenever $x\in A$, so every subset of $A$ is open, so every function with domain $A$ is continuous.

A topological space in which every subset is open is called a discrete space.